# Error While accessing the mvc aspx file from another mvc aspx file

Tags: model-view-controller

I created the aspx file in views folder and i set the hyper link in the default Home page in the same view folder and that link navigate to the aspx file i created.  When i run the application the home displayed but the error shows after i clicked the link:

> resource cannot found

Comment: NavigateUrl="~/Views/Student/EvaluvateStudent.aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used `<Html.ActionLink>` for navigation:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Evaluvate Student","EvaluvateStudent","Student") %>
```

In controller i used:

```
public ActionResult EvaluvateStudent()
{
   return View("Student");
}
```

Comment: Just making sure - if it's an answer, you did everything the way you should. +1 for me! You can mark this answer as accepted and get even more reputation points.